# How to determine Java Webstart application runs Test vs Prod?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, java-7, java-web-start

I have a feeling that there are still users pointing to the Test application. How can the user tell that they are on test vs prod? Right now they launch it from a shortcut on their desktop. Anything that we can do inside the app to warn them that they are on test?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that exposing the link to `Test` was an error,

- Specify a suitable [`update element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#update).

  ```
  <update check="always" policy="prompt-update">
  ```
- Remove `<offline-allowed/>`, if necessary, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876177/230513).
- Add a splash screen or modal dialog that notifies the user.
- Invoke `Desktop#browse()` on the desired link.
- Explain the benefits of updating promptly.
- Retire the errant link after a time.

Comment: In our case both the Test & the Production version points to Production DB. Some times the users are instructed to access Test instead of Production. And once things are fine again back to Production app. In such scenarios it will be better to warn the Users that they are using Test app. So if they use it by mistake they can change.

Comment: It sounds like the splash/dialog could be a regular part of `Test`, excluded from `Prod`, although I'm wary of exposing `Test`. Why not a _release candidate_ to verify the fix and catch regressions?